# Consulta ionic angular firebase

Tags: firebase, ionic

tengo problemas al obtener una colección desde **firebase** tengo el siguiente método

```
usuarioActual(){
     Var userId = this.AUauth.auth.currentUser.uid;
      Return 
      this.db.collection('users').doc(userId).valueChanges
}
```

Pero no se como continuar con la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguientes que debes hacer es suscribirte a la promesa que retorna firebase, de este modo los cambios se actualizan en tiempo real a doble via, es decir, los cambios que se hagan en firebase se reflejan automaticamente en tu app, y los cambios que hagas en tu app se reflejan automaticamente en firebase. La funcion subscribe le debes pasar una funcion que realizara las acciones que quieres hacer con los datos que llegan, generalmente se asignan a una variable, y opcionalmente le puedes pasar otra funcion para procesar cuando ocurra un error, generalmente lo que se hace es un console.log para ver que sucedio.

Se realizaria de la siguiente manera:

```
usuarioActual(){
  Var userId = this.AUauth.auth.currentUser.uid;
  return this.db.collection('users').doc(userId).valueChanges().subscribe(
    (datos)=>{procesas los datos que llegan de firebase, puede ser this.variable = data},
    (error)=>{procesas el error, puede ser un console.log(error)}
  )
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] , asi ganaras unas medallas y sabras como funcionamos, tambien te invito a leer [answer]